# React webkit prefix for position sticky

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webkit, prefix

It is possible to use the webkit prefix in React by adding Webkit to the styles.

For example: `WebkitTransform: 'rotate(90deg)'` instead of `transform: 'rotate(90deg)'`

But how can I add the webkit prefix to `'position: sticky'`?